How can we cut the powerset axiom into 5 incompatible parts?
I was curious if we take an axiom such as the axiom of powerset in ZF.
If there is an easy way to generate 5 axioms with the property that:

any 3 of the 5 axioms if taken together implies a weaker condition than the axiom of power set and that each of these is independent. (That is any one $3$-tuple $(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ DOES NOT imply a different $3$-tuple $(u_1', u_2', u_3')$) and moreover the powerset axiom is stronger than ALL of these tuples. I.E. each tuple is implied by the powerset axiom.

any 4 of the 5 axioms taken together is EQUIVALENT to the axiom of powerset.

all 5 of the axioms taken together is inconsistent.


How could one go about creating such axioms? My creativity seems to be limited here.

Item 2 guarantees that all the axioms are compatible with power set, so item 3 cannot happen

I don't understand the question.

@RossMillikan You’re right. This was a dumb question. If you can post answer I would be happy to accept!

@upvoter the question had a trivial solution. But thanks anyways. Feel free to remove your upvote as well.
